# Merge Data Frames of different years

Tags: r

im trying to merge some dataframes using R. You can find the dataframe here https://www.kaggle.com/mathurinache/world-happiness-report.

There are 6 dataframes, each for one year (2015-2020).

Is there anyway of merging this dateframes  using the year as a new  column?

```
Ex:
Year Country     Region
2015 Switzerland Western Europe  ...
2016 Switzerland Western Europe  ...
2017 Switzerland Western Europe  ...
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the data to your computer or do you just want to read it directly to the computer from the site?

Comment: I have the data on my computer.
I want to know if there are any functions that makes what im trying to show

Comment: well then : `m <- c("2015.csv", "2016.csv",...); do.call(rbind,lapply(m, function(x) cbind(year = sub("\\.csv","",x), read.csv(x)))` should do the trick

Comment: You should mention in your question that the files have not identical number of columns and even for the columns they have in common, they use slightly different names. Maybe you can update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to clean the data so that it contains the same columns. I gave it a shot, but it's not perfect yet. You still need to figure out how healthy life expectancy is defined across each year. In 2020 it seems to be a number in years, in 2019 it seems to be a standardized value and in the other years it is probably the proportion relative to the real life expectancy. Further, the log transformation of GDP in 2020 is my best guess, so no guarantee that this brings the 2020 data on the same scale as the rest of the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

mypath <- "Insert/Your/Path/Here/"

file_ls <- paste0(mypath, list.files(path = mypath, pattern = "*.csv"))

dat_ls <- tibble(year = 2015:2020, # setup a nested tibble
                 data = set_names(map(file_ls, ~ read.csv(.x) %>% as_tibble), year)) %>% 
          # mutate the 2020 data to match the other years
          mutate(data = map_at(data, "2020",
                               ~ mutate(.x,
                                        Rank = rank(desc(Ladder.score)),
                                        Logged.GDP.per.capita = log(exp(Logged.GDP.per.capita), exp(8)))
                               )) %>% 
          # enter here more map_at calls to transform the life expectancy column
          # ...
          # switch to rowwise, so that `map` etc is no longer needed
          rowwise(year) %>% 
          # select names in each data set in given order and then rename them with set_names
          mutate(data2 = list(select(data, 
                                     contains("country"), 
                                     contains("rank"),
                                     contains("score") & !contains("Dystopia") & !contains("standard"),
                                     contains("gdp") & !contains("explained"),
                                     contains("expectancy") & !contains("explained")
                                     ) %>% 
                                set_names(., c("country",
                                               "rank",
                                               "happiness_score",
                                               "gdp_per_capita",
                                               "life_expectancy"))
                              )) %>% 
        select(year, data2) %>% 
  unnest(data2)
```

Comment: Hi, i came up with another question.
Assume that i have one dataframe for each year and i want to use multiple filters using dplyr package ( filter, select, etc ).
Is there anyway to apply this filter to all dataframes ( using something like lapply)?